# bash search and replace a line after a certain line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a big yaml file containing multiple declaration blocks, related to different services.

The structure is similar to the following (but repeated for multiple applications):

```
- name: commerce-api
  type: helm
  version: 0.0.5
```

I would like to find the block of code that is containing `commerce-api` and replace the `version` property value with something else.

The thing is, I wrote this script:

```
bumpConfig() {
  LINE=$(awk "/- name: $1$/{print NR + $2}" "$CONFIG_YML")
  sed -i "" -E "${LINE}s/version: $3.*$/\version: $4/" "$CONFIG_YML"
}

bumpConfig "commerce-api" 2 "$OLD_APP_VERSION" "$NEW_APP_VERSION"
```

Which is kind of allowing me to do what I want, but the only problem is that, the property version is not always on the third line.

How can I make my script to look for the first occurrence of `version` given the service name to be `commerce-api`?

Is this even possible using `awk`?

Comment: Why switch from awk to sed? Practically anything you can do in sed can also be done in awk, so just do them in the same script.

Comment: You could also do it entirely in `sed`, since you can use a pattern match in the line range for the `s///` command.

Comment: @markp-fuso I'm looking for an exact match, I updated my original message

Comment: By only providing 1 block in your example and it containing the string you want to change, you're getting answers that'd also change other blocks. Add at least 1 more block that shouldn't change. Your existing example isn't adequate to test with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some variation to the input file:

```
$ cat config.yml
- name: commerce-api-skip
  type: helm
  version: 0.0.5
    - name: commerce-api
      type: helm
      bogus line1: bogus value1
      version: 0.0.5
      bogus line2: bogus value2
- name: commerce-api-skip-too
  type: helm
  version: 0.0.5
```

One `awk` idea:

```
bumpConfig() {
    awk -v name="$1" -v old="$2" -v new="$3" '
    /- name: /                { replace=0
                                if ($NF == name)
                                   replace=1
                              }
    replace && $1=="version:" { if ($NF == old)
                                   $0=substr($0,1,index($0,old)-1) new
                              }
    1
    ' "${CONFIG_YML}"
}
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
CONFIG_YML='config.yml'

name='commerce-api'
OLD_APP_VERSION='0.0.5'
NEW_APP_VERSION='0.0.7'

bumpConfig "${name}" "${OLD_APP_VERSION}" "${NEW_APP_VERSION}"
```

This generates:

```
- name: commerce-api-skip
  type: helm
  version: 0.0.5
    - name: commerce-api
      type: helm
      bogus line1: bogus value1
      version: 0.0.7
      bogus line2: bogus value2
- name: commerce-api-skip-too
  type: helm
  version: 0.0.5
```

Once OP is satisfied with the result:

- if running `GNU awk` the file can be updated 'in place' via: `awk -i inplace -v name="$1" ...`
- otherwise the output can be saved to a temp file and then copy the temp file over the original: `awk -v name="$1" ... > tmpfile; mv tmpfile "${CONFIG_YML}"`

Answer (score 1):

Entirely in `sed`

```
sed -i '' "s/^version: $3/version: $4/' "$CONFIG_YML"
```

`/^- name: $1\$/,/^- name:/` restricts the `s` command to just the lines between the requested name and the next `- name:` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_APP_VERSION=0.0.5
NEW_APP_VERSION=0.0.7
CONFIG_YML=config.yml

bumpConfig() {
    gawk -i inplace -v name="$1" -v old="$2" -v new="$3" '
        1
        /^- name: / && $3 == name {
            while (getline > 0) {
                if (/^  version: / && $2 == old)
                    $0 = "  version: " new
                print
                if (!NF || /^-/ || /^  version: /)
                    break
            }
        }
    ' "${CONFIG_YML}"
}

bumpConfig commerce-api "${OLD_APP_VERSION}" "${NEW_APP_VERSION}"
```